# value of ints in if statements in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, int

so in my class I have a recording function (2 buttons, start & stop recording) and a leave your name function (TextEdit). It's the second screen of my survey app and I want that if the user does not give any input at the second screen for 20 seconds the app jumps back to the first screen.

```
public class Name extends Activity {

Button mButton;
EditText mEdit;
String name;
int a = 0;   //AudioRecorder starts here 
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private int currentFormat = 0;
private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };
private String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4, AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP };

private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

}
private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}
private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}
private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(Name.this, "Error: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(Name.this, "Warning: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnStart: {
                Toast.makeText(Name.this, "Start Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButtons(true);
                startRecording();
                a=a+1;
                break;
            }
            case R.id.btnStop: {
                Toast.makeText(Name.this, "Stop Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButtons(false);
                stopRecording();
                a=a-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name);

    // getting the name
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = mEdit.getText().toString();
           //sending the name to an email address
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                                "mailaddress",
                                "PW");
                       sender.sendMail(name, name + " made the last input",
                                "mailaddress",
                                "mailaddress");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.THANKYOU"));
            if (a==1){
                Toast.makeText(Name.this, "Stop Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButtons(false);
                stopRecording();
            }
        }
    });

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&a==0) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.THANKYOU"));
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
//Audio Record
    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);
}}
```

So my question is, if i press the start and stop button a should be 0 and therefore this if statement should come in

```
if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&a==0)
```

However, once I pressed the start button it doesn't matter what I press after that if statement never jumps in again.

any ideas?

Comment: Just checking the `mEdit` is the name and its empty?

Comment: yes, mEdit is the name of my TextEdit and if it's left empty, the app is supposed to go to the new activity (.THANKYOU)

Comment: Would you mind clarify which code belong to which activity?

Comment: With this broken code blocks I don't think anyone would be able to help you. Please add code block correctly.

Comment: ok, I copied the whole code in it  thank you !

Comment: Is it possible that control is reaching `startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.THANKYOU"));` but the `startActivity` part is not working can you put a log there and see ?

Comment: if I don't press anything it works perfectly fine, the app jumps to the THANKYOU screen. Only if I click the start recording button and stop recording it won't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler code should be in an `onResume()` block so it gets called each time the view is shown. I'm not sure if you meant to have the value of your delay "2000" which is 2 seconds or "20000" which is 20 seconds as you state in the post.  When I up the time to 20 seconds and did some testing, everything worked correctly once I moved the Handler block out as follows:

```
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0 && a==0) {
                    startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.THANKYOU"));
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 20000);
    }
```

Comment: That works the same way the other one works: If i press the start and stop button within the time frame it jumps automatically to the new activity. However, if I record for longer than the time frame the screen stays there. Somehow, once you extend the time frame the handler doesn't work anymore

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want the following to happen:
If no input for 20 seconds move to next screen.
If user hits start then stop within 20 seconds and no text move to next screen after the initial 20 seconds has elapsed. 
If user hits start then 20 seconds elapses, after the 20 seconds the user hits stop, move to next screen when the user hits stop.  

is that correct?

Comment: No, I want: If no input for 20 seconds then move to the next screen. If the user hits the record button, it is an input, if he types in his name, it is an input. If he hits the record button then the stop button and then nothing, it is no input, ergo no input for 20 seconds, move to the next screen.